# Omnet++ Simulation regarding switch

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to simulate a network in Omnet++ 5.5.1 version using a switch, but the switch is also doing broadcasting how to make a switch to send a packet to a particular node in a network.

Could you please help me out regarding this question?

Answer (score 0):

The switch does broadcast arp packets. Just have to put a few standard hosts as well as a switch. Remember to configure your Ipv4 network followed by ur gates between all the devices. There is PingApp, TCPApp as well as UDPApp to send packets between devices.